# GET subdomain html page with jquery

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

I have the following situation.

From an application located in *https://subdomain.mydomain.com* I am trying to get the html of a page located in *https://mydomain.com/page.aspx*

I'm doing this with the jquery *$.ajax* method.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            console.info("success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    });
```

The aspx page is actually called and executed.

IE (through XDomainRequest) and Firefox have the same behavior: from the inspectors (IE dev tools and Firebug) I see that the response status is *200 OK* and it has the expected size (80KB) but the response content is empty. 
The jQuery error is not so useful:

```
    readyState: 0,  
    responseText: ""
    status: 0,
    statusText: "error"
```

I guess it's something involving the Same Origin Policy. I see people solving this kind of issues with YQL (but i don't want to use additional libraries) and JSONP (but I'm working with plain HTML).

In a moment of desperation I have tried also tricks like

```
    document.domain = 'mydomain.com';
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

No success. Any tip?

---

The problem was due to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` that must be enabled on the called application. In my case, it was an asp.net application in IIS7 hosting. I had to add these lines in the web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The following website reports many configuration to [enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org) on many server types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use IE's or FF's cross-origin requests you need to tune up your server side to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with the response. And if you want to use `document.domain` it must be set not only at the requesting side, but in the response too. So you can use iframe to send such a request or use SCRIPT or JSONP since they have no cross-origin limitations.

Comment: That worked! I just had to add to right server configuration. This link helped me a lot 
http://enable-cors.org/

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use JSONP to get the data

```
function myFunc() {
    console.info("success");
}

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    'dataType': "jsonp",
    'jsonp': "callback",
    'jsonpCallback': "myFunc"
});
```

The problem is that you are trying to make an XHR request from another domain, which is not allowed. You told jQuery to allow CORS, but JSONP is a better way to do this. You will need to set your server-side code to return the html in JSON data wrapped in a function to be called when the URL is loaded.

Comment: I'll consider this options when I have to face an existing JSON service. Thank you for your help!

Comment: That is very understandable. I recently had a project with a very similar problem. I set up my server-side code to listen for the `?callback=xxx` query string and return all of the HTML in a JSON variable instead of a plain HTML response. I guess I should have mentioned that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As simple javascript will suffice

```
alert(document.domain);

console.log("Output;");  
console.log(location.hostname);
console.log(document.domain);
alert(window.location.hostname)

console.log("document.URL : "+document.URL);
console.log("document.location.href : "+document.location.href);
console.log("document.location.origin : "+document.location.origin);
console.log("document.location.hostname : "+document.location.hostname);
console.log("document.location.host : "+document.location.host);
console.log("document.location.pathname : "+document.location.pathname);
```